# issue creating compute in Machine learning

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, azure-image

Getting the following when trying to add compute to my machine learning pipline,

The specified subscription has a total vCPU quota of 0 and is less than the requested compute training cluster and/or compute instance's min nodes of 1 which maps to 1 vCPUs

Answer (score 1):

Azure blog statement on new subscription restrictions:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

Another official response to your problem from the Azure `Consumption`/`Service Experience` team:

> This page [Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and
>   constraints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits) lists some of the most common Azure limits, which are
>   also called quotas. You can find out your [current usage and quota
>   limits for each subscription in the Azure Portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/networking/check-usage-against-limits)​. Find out more
>   about quota increase requests by reading [Resource Manager vCPU quota
>   increase requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request) – then submit your request by opening an [online
>   customer support request](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) at no charge.

Source: Internal `SharePoint` site for the `Service Experience` team.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same to me but on AWS, I'm pretty sure you are seeing this on Azure. You have to basically create a ticket requesting increase of the service. Each family type of the compute service has different limits.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/regional-quota-requests

https://knowledge.mycloudit.com/request-core-increase-azure-subscription